# JBossCache - Access cache from separate Java app

Tags: jboss-cache

My company wants to investigate the option of launching one java app that simply configures and starts a cache on an app server, then have a separate stand alone app call that instance from the first program and write to/read from it.

We currently have a job that access to data is slow, but if we can load the data and always have it available on the same machine, this may be a good bet to help access speed.

There are no examples I am finding to having a separate project access that cache.

If anyone has any direction or a URL of an example I would appreciate it.

Or if this is easier to accomplish in another open souce available, please give your opinion.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

JBoss is a very heavy hammer to build a cache.

Did you consider [memcached](http://memcached.org/) ?

If you like to stay on the JVM, I just found that [ehcache can run as a standalone server](http://ehcache.org/documentation/cache_server.html#Installing_the_Standalone_Server).

Comment: No, I have not. I just started looking at options, so I am getting suggestions of things that have worked for others. I am not set on JBoss at all, but that is the first name you usually hear. I am looking for the easiest and most lightweight option.

Comment: Memcached is a single purpose program which is as simple as it gets.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion I will definitely look into this

Comment: we have used ehcache for local caching, but being on a different machine it would not be within the JVM and remote access was not obvious, but worth more investigation